# A tree on 5 vertices of which two are of degree three?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I wanted to know if my solution is correct. I am not sure if such questions are right for this site. Please let me know if this isn't.

**Question:** Is there a tree with 5 vertices of which two are of degree 3?

**My Solution:** Consider a tree with 5 vertices. Thus by theorem (which states that a tree on n vertices has n-1 edges), it should have 5-1=4 edges.

By handshaking lemma, total degree of the tree (sum of degrees of all vertices) is 2$\times$ (No. of edges) = 2$\times$4 =8

This tree has 2 vertices each of degree 3 $\implies$ The sum of degrees of remaining 3 vertices is 8-3-3=2

Now, it is impossible to have 3 vertices in a tree with sum of degrees = 2 without having at least one of the vertices have degree zero. (*I think this line in my proof isn't rigorous enough*)

But if at least one of the vertices have degree zero, the graph cannot be a tree as it becomes disconnected (A tree by definition is a connected acyclic undirected graph)

Does this proof make sense?

Comment: Yes, this looks good. Another approach is to show that the number of vertices that are connected to both $a$ and $b$ is at least $v(a) + v(b) - n +1 = 3 + 3 - 5 + 1 = 2$, thus we have a 4-cycle.

Comment: Your argument is correct. You can make it a little nicer by observing that every vertex of a tree has degree at least $1$, so if there are two vertices of degree $3$, the sum of the degrees must be at least $9$, and therefore it must have more than $4$ edges, which is impossible for a tree on $5$ vertices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses!! I will make the necessary improvements